# Finding failure probability distibution for a parameter over time

Tags: time-series, probability, distributions

We have a function `P (t, x)` that indicates a failure probability (for some experiment) for a given time `t` and a parameter`x`. For a given `t` probability is 0 for `x < x_min (t)`, 1 for `x > x_max (t)` and linear in between. We have a series of measurements that shows if fail happened. Something like this:

```
t = 325.108529  x = 0.080805 ok,    x = 0.101006 fail
t = 325.189335  x = 0.080805 ok 
t = 325.27014   x = 0.079488 ok,    x = 0.09936 fail
t = 325.349628  x = 0.079488 ok 
t = 325.429116  x = 0.078874 ok,    x = 0.098592 fail
t = 325.50799   x = 0.063099 ok,    x = 0.078874 fail
t = 325.571089  x = 0.063099 ok 
t = 325.634188  x = 0.070272 ok,    x = 0.08784 fail
```

We need to assess `x_min (t)` and `x_max (t)` for the next time `t`. What are the methods that could be applied here?

Comment: Is this homework, by any chance?

Comment: @jbowman No, I'm trying to optimize some process at my job - basically we need to choose x as large as possible, but without too many failures

Comment: By "linear", do you mean that the probability increases from 0 to 1 linearly between $x_{min}$ and $x_{max}$, or that it is constant - it jumps from 0 to some probability at $x_{min}$, stays at that probability until $x_{max}$, then jumps to 1?

Comment: @jbowman probability increases linearly from 0 to 1